# Is there any way to redirect to our react native app from an existing app?

Tags: react-native

is there any way to redirect to our react native app when user clicks an existing app (example: if a user clicks facebook app it should redirect to our react native app)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can open your app depending upon some url. However, user has to click the link. Otherwise no, unless the "other app" is written by you!

Comment: Is it possible to do it in any other framework apart from react native?

Comment: The concept is called linking, you can check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) for more info. And yes it can be done with any reputed android development framework, be it flutter or cordova or xamrin.